# Smtp Exception Authenticated address

Tags: c#, smtp

I'm doing a job that migrates a database, when a error happens it should send an email, but I got this error "From address must match authenticated address".

I'm passing this values, but I don't know what it's wrong.

```
EmailTO mail = new EmailTO()
            {
                ENABLE_SSL = "false",
                IsBodyHtml = true,
                MailFROM = "erro@starcorp.com.br",
                MailTO = "vinicius.cano@starcorp.com.br",
                Message = ex.Message + texto,
                NameFROM = "Daniel Golfieri",
                NameTO = "Erros - Poupe Compre",
                SMTP = "smtp.clientes.starcorp.com.br",
                SMTP_AUTHENTICATE = "true",
                SMTP_PASSWORD = "XXXXX",
                SMTP_PORTA = "XXX",
                SMTP_USER = "daniel.golfieri@starcorp.com.br",
                Subject = "[PoupeCompre] Erro na Migração de Produtos"
            };
```

I think something is wrong in the emails I'm passing.

Comment: What happens if you change the "MailFROM" to "daniel.golfieri@starcorp.com.br"?

Comment: I got the same error

Comment: Is the error being generated by the SMTP server?

Comment: I'm getting this error in the job application,the full error msg is "{"mailbox not available. The servers returns was: From address must match authenticated address"}"

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what's wrong. "From address (erro@starcorp.com.br) must match authenticated address (daniel.golfieri@starcorp.com.br)." It seems pretty straight forward to me. Change the From address to match the Authenticated address.

Comment: Already tried that,got the same error.